# Alternative to "In real time"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a better alternative to "in real time"? For example:

> People tweet in real time.
>
> People tweet *live*. [seems kind of unnatural to me]

Comment: People tweeting on the fly?

Comment: Why does 'live' unnatural for you?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to convey? The fact that humans do everything "in real time" (because we have not mastered the 4th dimension) or that they don't wait until later, and if they are going to tweet that they will do it instantaneously or not at all?

Comment: "Spontaneously" might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*On the spot* is the best I can think of.

On Oxford Dictionary of English we can read: "without any delay; immediately."

The book "Cool Tools for the Connected Classroom" by Anne Mirtschin reports:

> Messages, or 'tweets' [...]. It can be the fastest and most effective
>   way of getting a message  out and an **on-the-spot** response.